# How to prevent WebStorm IDE from opening '.html' files in a web browser on double-clicking it?

Tags: html, webstorm

I am trying to name a HTML file as `index.html` in the WebStorm IDE. However, I am unable to open this file to *edit* it if I name it `index` - it directly opens in the browser.

I can open other `.html` files in WebStorm for editing if they are named something other than `index.html`.

If I go to `Refactor > Rename` and change the name of `index.html` file to something else, I am *again* not able to edit it.

It seems like there must be a setting for this somewhere but I cannot figure out what or where.

Comment: Are you double-clicking the file, and expecting it to open in WebStorm?

Comment: Double clicking to open the file in WebStorm is working for an `.html` file with any other filename than `index`. WebStorm hates `index` idk why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have told IDE to open it like that in the past (on purpose or by mistake) .. so it keeps doing it.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Find `Files Opened in Associated Application` entry in top list
3. Find and remove offending entry from bottom list (most likely will be `index.html` or similar)

Comment: This was __exactly__ the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: After resolving the problem in this way, the title of my question no longer looks like it could help others in a similar situation. Can you suggest a better question?

Comment: @Ketcomp "WebStorm always opens index.html in a browser instead of editing on double click" -- something along these lines